# Can w3m automatically search the entered text?

Tags: internet, web, w3m

Is there a way to configure w3m so that with 'U', i.e. after entering text into the URL field, the browser will automatically prepend "google.com/search?q=" to it?

Or can some other command be used or defined to obtain the same effect? I tried calling a shell script via "#" but it just passes output into buffer.

Comment: @jasonwryan: this doesn't apply when w3m is already running

Comment: Er, no. But it does exactly what you are asking about (and a whole lot more)...

Comment: For DuckDuckGo there's a dedicated tool: https://github.com/jarun/ddgr

Answer (score 3):

I added this to my ~/.profile

```
goo() {
    IFS=+ w3m https://google.com/search?hl=en\&q="$*"\&btnI= https://google.com/search?hl=en\&q="$*"
}
```

This allows a quick look at "I'm Feeling Lucky" result on a command line like this: `goo linux kernel`. If first match is a miss, hitting B presents the normal list of results. The convenience comes at expense of latency though, as both URLs load before anything is displayed.

Comment: i didn't notice that the original question was about searching from within w3m

Comment: Great function. For zsh compatability I use ```goo() {
        query=$(echo "$*" | xargs | sed -E 's/\s+/\+/g')
        w3m "https://google.com/search?hl=en\&q=$query"
}```

Answer (score 1):

You need only configure google.cgi plugin:

`cp /path-to-w3m-sources/Bonus/google.cgi /usr/lib/w3m/cgi-bin
chmod +x /usr/lib/w3m/cgi-bin/google.cgi`

Create protocol g:

`echo  'g: file:/usr/lib/w3m/cgi-bin/google.cgi?%s'' >> ~/.w3m/urimethodmap`

Edit google.cgi, find this line:

`$url .= "search?q=$_&hl=ja&lr=lang_ja&ie=EUC-JP";`

Adjust for english:

`$url .= "search?q=$_&hl=en&ie=UTF-8";`

Now you can search in URL prompt of w3m like `g:my+google+query`

Answer (score 1):

You can map a macro hotkey to do a 'smart search' for different search engines. Once you hit the hotkey it will open a new tab then take you directly to the text field to type in your keyword:

```
$EDITOR ~/.w3m/keymap

keymap  sd      COMMAND "TAB_GOTO https://duckduckgo.com/lite/; NEXT_LINK; GOTO_LINK; SUBMIT"
keymap  sg      COMMAND "TAB_GOTO https://google.com; GOTO_LINE 6; NEXT_LINK; GOTO_LINK; SUBMIT"
keymap  sy      COMMAND "TAB_GOTO https://yewtu.be; NEXT_LINK; GOTO_LINK"
keymap  so      COMMAND "TAB_GOTO https://search.yahoo.com; GOTO_LINE 19; NEXT_LINK; GOTO_LINK"
```

Usage example: hit **sg** type in *hello world* then hit enter